# boost1.44.0 filesystem v3 can not run properly on solaris sparc 64bit platform

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, filesystems, solaris

I used `boost::filesystem::is_directory()` in my program, the problem is when I compile my program with option `-DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3`, the program cannot run properly. The boost version is 1.44.0.

Specifically, I build the filesystem library by the following command:

```
./bjam --toolset=gcc define=BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3 --with-filesystem stage
```

I build my program with a command like this.

```
g++ -I boost_1_44_0_folder test.cpp -o test boost_1_44_0_folder/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a boost_1_44_0_folder/stage/lib/libboost_system.a -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3
```

When I execute ./test, the result is "is not dir".

But if I build my program with a command like this.

```
g++ -I boost_1_44_0_folder test.cpp -o test boost_1_44_0_folder/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a boost_1_44_0_folder/stage/lib/libboost_system.a
```

When I execute ./test, the result is "is dir".

And my test code is shown as follows.

`test.cpp`

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    namespace bf = boost::filesystem;
    bf::path p("/home");
    if (!boost::filesystem::is_directory(p)) {
        cout << "is not dir" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "is dir" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `/home` a directory? Is it a symlink? A mountpoint?

Comment: for other directory, it is same.

Comment: What GCC version are you using?  Boost will push the limits of just about every C++ compiler, and the version that Oracle ships with Solaris tends to be a bit dated.  (And if you're using a version of Solaris shipped by Sun, it's really dated...)

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to upgrade your Boost version.  If you look at the source code (for example: http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/wave/util/filesystem_compatibility.hpp) there are lots of changes in the filesystem processing in version 1.0.46 and 1.0.50, with a lot of code looking like this:

```
#if BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION >= 3
#if BOOST_VERSION >= 105000
        return boost::filesystem::complete(p, base);
#else
        return boost::filesystem3::complete(p, base);
#endif
#else
        return boost::filesystem::complete(p, base);
#endif
```

FWIW, this code in operations.cpp (http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp) really bothers me:

```
// both stats now known to be valid
return  s1.st_dev == s2.st_dev && s1.st_ino == s2.st_ino
    // According to the POSIX stat specs, "The st_ino and st_dev fields
    // taken together uniquely identify the file within the system."
    // Just to be sure, size and mod time are also checked.
    && s1.st_size == s2.st_size && s1.st_mtime == s2.st_mtime;
```

Thus if you're checking if two files are actually the same file with Boost, and they really are the same file but it gets written to or even just `touch`'d at the wrong moment, Boost will return that the file isn't itself.  That, in addition to not properly identifying something as common as a simple directory, does not give me a lot of confidence in the rest of the Boost filesystem implementation.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your answer. I think I have find out the root cause.It is a bug of boost 1.44.0 filesystem v3. You may see the ticket #5355. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5355